# How can I remove repeated rows in a two-dimensional array? Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a two-dimensional array, and if there are repeated date+substance of material, I want to find the average of the values. A new two-dimensional array should be constituted with no repeated dates+substances.

```java
    String [] [] array = {
        {"804", "2007-01-02", "1", "Alkalinity", "38.6"},
        {"804", "2007-01-02", "1", "Alkalinity", "39.6"},
        {"804", "2007-01-02", "1",  "PH", "36.6"},
        {"804", "2007-01-02", "1", "Conductivity", "40.8"},
        {"804", "2008-10-02", "10",  "Alkalinity", "39.5"},
        {"817", "04-10-99", "10",  "Alkalinity",  "38.4"},
        {"826", "04-10-99", "10", "PH",  "38.2"}
    } ;
```

This is an example of a part of the array. Since the first two rows have the same date and are both on alkalinity, their values (38.6 and 39.6) should be averaged. A new array list should be created with one less row. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or how to improve the quality of your question. Then edit your question to include your full source code you have as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be compiled and tested by others. Currently you are not asking any question.

Comment: You just laid out the parameters for the answer to your own question. Why don't you try to implement your requirements in code? How would you compare and remove duplicate elements in an array? Start there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to sort the rows based on the value of date and alkalinity. Then, navigate the array and merge the rows having the same date and alkalinity as per your requirement. Given below is the code for the same:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] [] array = {
                {"804", "2007-01-02", "1", "Alkalinity", "38.6"},
                {"804", "2007-01-02", "1", "Alkalinity", "39.6"},
                {"804", "2007-01-02", "1",  "PH", "36.6"},
                {"804", "2007-01-02", "1", "Conductivity", "40.8"},
                {"804", "2008-10-02", "10",  "Alkalinity", "39.5"},
                {"817", "04-10-99", "10",  "Alkalinity",  "38.4"},
                {"826", "04-10-99", "10", "PH",  "38.2"}
            } ;

        List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            list.add(array[i]);
        Collections.sort(list, arrComparator);

        System.out.println("Sorted list:");
        for (String[] s : list)
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));

        List<String[]> newList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        String[] strArr = list.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
            double sum = 0.0;
            int count = 1;
            while (strArr[1].equals(list.get(i)[1]) && strArr[3].equals(list.get(i)[3])) {
                sum += Double.parseDouble(strArr[4]) + Double.parseDouble(list.get(i)[4]);
                strArr = list.get(i);
                i++;
                count++;
            }
            if (count > 1) {
                newList.add(new String[] { strArr[0], strArr[1], strArr[2], strArr[3], String.valueOf(sum / count) });
            } else {
                newList.add(strArr);
            }
            strArr = list.get(i);
        }
        newList.add(list.get(list.size() - 1));

        System.out.println("Final list:");
        for (String[] s : newList)
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
    }

    public static Comparator<String[]> arrComparator = new Comparator<String[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String[] strArr1, String[] strArr2) {
            String date1 = strArr1[1];
            String date2 = strArr2[1];
            int sComp = date1.compareTo(date2);
            if (sComp != 0) {
                return sComp;
            }
            return strArr1[3].compareTo(strArr2[3]);
        }
    };
}
```

**Output:**

```
Sorted list:
[817, 04-10-99, 10, Alkalinity, 38.4]
[826, 04-10-99, 10, PH, 38.2]
[804, 2007-01-02, 1, Alkalinity, 38.6]
[804, 2007-01-02, 1, Alkalinity, 39.6]
[804, 2007-01-02, 1, Conductivity, 40.8]
[804, 2007-01-02, 1, PH, 36.6]
[804, 2008-10-02, 10, Alkalinity, 39.5]
Final list:
[817, 04-10-99, 10, Alkalinity, 38.4]
[826, 04-10-99, 10, PH, 38.2]
[804, 2007-01-02, 1, Alkalinity, 39.1]
[804, 2007-01-02, 1, Conductivity, 40.8]
[804, 2007-01-02, 1, PH, 36.6]
[804, 2008-10-02, 10, Alkalinity, 39.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the following idea:
You have to check each row with the row following it. 
If any of the following rows are equal to the row you check, dont add it to the list. 
I wrote this code:

```
ArrayList<String[]> arrayListUniqueRows = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++){
  boolean rowToAdd = true; //potential i row is to add to list
  for(int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++){
    boolean sameRows = true; //two potential rows are equal
    for(int k = 0; k < array[k].length; k++){
      if(!array[i][k].equals(array[j][k])){ //check if they are
        sameRows = false;
      }
    }
    if(sameRows){ //if they are signalize to not add i row to unique list
      System.out.println("Rows " + (i+1) + " and " + (j+1) + " are equal!");
      rowToAdd = false;
    }
  }
  if(rowToAdd){
    arrayListUniqueRows.add(array[i]);
  }
}
System.out.println(arrayListUniqueRows.size());
```

And it gives you an arraylist of unique rows. Do whatever you want with it.